# AlertDialog youtube?

Tags: android, layout-inflater

I want know if is possible inflate YouTube in a  alert dialog,

But always get this error in my view `View` : 
    `android.view.InflateException` exception.

**Inflate** :

```
 dialogView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.alert_label_editor_notif, null,false);
```

**XML**

```
 <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
                        android:id="@+id/youtube_view"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

Comment: Please post the entire error.

Answer (score 0):

Don't create a view for that.The easily ways to use [Youtube Stan Alone Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started)

I have made tutorial at [This Git Hub Link](https://github.com/mohit008/Android-Youtube-Stand-Alone-Player)

Sample .

[image: ouput]

Comment: I need a view, because I have text and another objects concurrents. not is alone video, srry, and now I see proyect YouTube Api 1.2.2 but I don't see how I can load alertdialog(view) + text

Comment: have to even checked the link....please go through it first...and as you question..put this whole think in a layout and put  `light mode off` as in code..

Comment: This picture not include (with this popup) in the Project :( !!

Comment: which picture not included?

Comment: Yes picture is so easy, but I want embedded video.

Comment: At [this](https://code.google.com/archive/p/youtube-api-samples/source/default/source) link there are other option available to use API